# When using polymorphic relationships in rails, I can't use underscores in my has_many attribute name (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism

My application uses a polymorhpic relationship like so:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :child_owner, polymorphic: true
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :children, as: :child_owner, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This setup works fine. However, when I change the attribute name of `:children` to a multiword variable like `:kids_of_parent`, I get an unintialized constant exception (for Parent::KidsOfParent). In my case, the multiword variable would be much more descriptive. What am I doing wrong? Can someone at least confirm this behaviour?

Thanks,

Chris

Using Rails 3.2.8 with ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should specify a class when use the name unconventional, like this:

```
has_many :kids_of_parent, as: :child_owner, class_name: "Child", dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense. Can't believe I convinced myself it was the underscore thing. Too long infront of the computer today.